# How do I parse JSON with multiline strings in Golang?

Tags: json, go, gson

I've got a [project that gets metadata from Minecraft mods](https://github.com/jamiemansfield/go-modmeta), and I'm [having some trouble](https://github.com/jamiemansfield/go-modmeta/issues/2) with the Minecraft Forge's old `mcmod.info` format - which is a JSON format read with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for those that don't know.

Specifically, GSON unfortunately allows for strings to be multi-line (it allows for unescaped newlines in a string) - which Go's `encoding/json` doesn't allow for. See the below example from the Chisel mod to see what I mean.

```
[{
  "credits": "AUTOMATIC_MAIDEN for the original mod,
asie for porting to 1.7.2,
and Pokenfenn/Cricket for continuing it in 1.7.
This mod uses textures from the Painterly Pack: http://painterlypack.net/."
}]
```

This results in an error of `invalid character '\n' in string literal`.

I did take a brief look at using an alternative JSON parser (the aptly-named [jsonparser](https://github.com/buger/jsonparser) specifically took my eye), but without testing them all - I've been unable to determine which, if any, support what I need.

I suspect the solution to this problem will be in using an alternative JSON parser, I'm just not aware enough of the available libraries or JSON's use in Golang to make a highly informed decision.

Comment: @jamierocks if you don't mind losing the new lines you could just replace them with space: https://play.golang.com/p/0risDenSLae

Comment: @mkopriva That could well be a good solution actually - thank you! I'm not actually reading the credits, which in the mods I've tested seems to where the multi-lines are - so losing them doesn't matter too much.

Comment: I tried jsonparser out as doing raw reading gives me better errors, which fortunately handles multi-line strings :D I'm going to stick with this for now, but I'm definately keeping it under review. https://github.com/jamiemansfield/go-modmeta/commit/70d0a12513dc1b5be58593b45fe29a51f0337faa